# Text Underline offset behind text

Tags: css

I want to show underline 50% behind the text. Like this 
[image]

When I try using `text-underline-offset` with negative value, the underline will get hidden. But if the negative value is high enough it will be shown above the text instead.

I expect "Third Link" to show underline slightly behind text. Is there anything I can add to make it work?

The code are
https://jsbin.com/kecuxitiha/edit?html,css,output

HTML

```
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <a href="#" class="first">First Link</a> text <a href="#" class="second">Second Text</a> of 
      the printing and typesetting industry.  <a href="#" class="third">Third Link</a>
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
```

CSS

```
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 6px;
  text-decoration-color: yellow;
}

.second {
  text-underline-offset: -21px;
}

.third {
  text-underline-offset: -4px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some creative use of pseudo elements can help solve this.

```css
.underline::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.underline {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text with a <span class="underline">special</span> underline</p>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Relatively position the element itself. And absolutely position either it's `::before` pseudo-element child or `::after` for the yellow rectangle.

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default..
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

a::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <a href="#" class="first">First Link</a> text <a href="#" class="second">Second Text</a> of the printing and typesetting industry. <a href="#" class="third">Third Link</a> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
  text ever since the 1500s,
</p>
```

You may adjust the `height` and `top` properties.